# How does adding a caret to the start of square brackets affect the result?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

What is the difference between:

```
grep "[-0-9]" xyz.lst
```

and:

```
grep "[^-0-9]" xyz.lst
```

Comment: ^ is negation of the class, so show lines with no '-' or numbers

Comment: what is the difference in output??

Comment: @user2196728 The meaning of the caret changes inside a character class.

Comment: @aet: That's wrong.  `[^-0-9]` matches any line that **does** contain at least one character that's not in the set `[-0-9]`.  You see the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `[-0-9]` is a character class for the character `-` and the range of characters `0-9` i.e. the following `-,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` *(it matches any digit or a hyphen)*. A character class starting with `^` is a negation of the class i.e. it matches anything **not** in that class.

**Demo**:

```
$ cat file
-
1
a
2
b
3
c
-

$ grep '[-0-9]' file
-
1
2
3
-

$ grep '[^-0-9]' file
a
b
c
```

Comment: what if the file contains
123
abc
123abc
abc123
-123
123-
abc123-
-abc123
-

Comment: I have no clue where the line break are in that input so it's impossible to say. Why not just try it yourself!?

Answer (score 1):

The caret (`^`) negates the class. So your first expression matches a minus sign and the numbers 0 to 9. In your second expression it will match anything that is *not* a minus sign or a digit.

Comment: is there a difference in [-0-9] and "[-0-9]" ?

Comment: The `"` here are delimiters for grep to indicate the pattern. They're not part of the pattern, so no.

Answer (score 0):

The second indicates negation "everything that is not..."

Answer (score 0):

One of those finds every line with a digit or a `-` (dash) character anywhere in the line.

The other finds every line with something that isn't a digit or a dash.

For example, both commands will find this line if it's in the file:

```
k9
```

Since that contains something that's a digit, and something that isn't.

Note that if what you want in the second case is "show me every line that doesn't contain a digit or dash", what you want is one of these: (either command will work)

```
grep -v '[-0-9]' xyz.lst
grep '^[^-0-9]*$' xyz.lst
```